# How to separate two arrays from within an array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to separate the two arrays, `regplates` and `distance`, from within `speeders` and output them next to each other:

```
require 'date'
# Variables and Constants.
speeders = Array.new
DISTANCE = 10
LIMIT = 70
MINTIME = DISTANCE/LIMIT

# Recieving input of regplate + Checking if they are speeding.
def calculations(speeders)
  puts "Please input your registration plate:"
  puts "Type 'stop' to stop."
  loop do
    regplate = gets.chomp
    break if regplate == 'stop'
    now = Time.now
    time1 = DateTime.strptime("13:22:45","%H:%M:%S")
    time2 = time1 + (rand(10) / ( 24.0 * 60))
    elapsed_time = time2 - time1 
    if elapsed_time >= MINTIME 
      speeders << [regplate, DISTANCE/elapsed_time.to_f]   
    end
  end
return speeders
end

# Outputting the speeders with their mph.
def speeder_output(speeders) 
  speeders.each do |regplate|
    printf("%s %i",regplate, DISTANCE)
  end
end  

speeders = calculations(speeders)
speeder_output(speeders)
```

Comment: Don't paste a long chunk of code. Post the minimum required to state your question.

Comment: Sorry, first time, didn't know that was the etiquette - If you could try answer my question that'd be very helpful.

Comment: Always begin a question with an explanation of what you want to achieve. If possible, include a small example with input values and show your desired output. (A variable should be assigned to each input, so readers can cut and paste and refer to those variables in answers and comments.) Only then present your code and ask why it doesn't work. Have a look at the [SO faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help) when you have time.

Comment: It's not too late to edit your question to do what I suggested. Among other things that may head off more downvotes and votes to close the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It'd be good for you to spend more time taking the tutorials. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Please reduce your code to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem, supply minimal data necessary to reproduce the problem, and an example of your expected output. Don't ask us to generate data or comb through a lot of code as it wastes our time when we could be helping others. In other words, we expect you to help us when we help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you recognized, the array is an array of arrays.  You can just output each element of the sub-array.

```
# Outputting the speeders with their mph.
def speeder_output(speeders) 
  speeders.each do |reg, speed|
    printf("%s %i",reg, speed)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Sorry for bad formatting

Comment: Yes, excellent suggestion, @CarySwoveland

Comment: It isn't necessary to add notes saying you "Edited:" or "Updated:" something in a question or answer. We have the ability to see revisions if necessary. Instead, simply make the changes and add new information where it would have been initially placed. Think of it this way: We're writing a cookbook of programming problems and solutions. If we looked in a reference book it wouldn't be full of "edits" and "updates" would it?